# Way to track mp3 listening by third party?

Tags: mp3

If someone downloads an mp3 file from my servers, is there any way I can graft some sort of trigger onto the mp3 so that I can tell when that person listens to the mp3 file?

Answer (score 0):

If it's really an MP3 file, then no.